# Copy entire directory in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a directory structure like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
dir1/
    file3.txt
    file4.txt
```

I want to use [Gradle to copy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files) that entire structure into another directory. I tried this:

```
task mytest << {
    copy {
        from "file1.txt"
        from "file2.txt"
        from "dir1"

        into "mytest"
    }
}
```

But this results in the following:

```
mytest/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    file3.txt
    file4.txt
```

See, the copy from `dir1` copied the files *in* `dir1`, whereas I want to copy `dir1` *itself*.

Is it possible to do this directly with [Gradle copy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files)?

So far, I have only been able to come up with this solution:

```
task mytest << {
    copy {
        from "file1.txt"
        from "file2.txt"

        into "mytest"
    }

    copy {
        from "dir1"
        into "mytest/dir1"
    }
}
```

For my simple example there's not much to it, but in my actual case there are many directories I want to copy, and I'd like to not have to repeat so much.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `.` as the directory path and `include` to specify, which files and directories you want to copy:

```
copy {
    from '.'
    into 'mytest'
    include 'file*.txt'
    include 'dir1/**'
}
```

If both `from` and `into` are directories, you'll end up with the full copy of the source directory in the destination directory.

Comment: The problem with this is if I have other files in this folder that I do *not* want to copy. I can use `excludes` parameter, but that would be error prone as other subdirectories might be added in the future.

Comment: Does `include` work for you? I've expanded the answer to show how to specify files/dirs you want to copy.

Comment: Actually, I needed to do `include "dir1/**"` to copy dir1 and everything under it. Otherwise it only copied an empty dir1 directory.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late, but I tried @Andrew solution above and it copied everything inside the directory.
"." is not required nowadays to represent a direct in gradle.
So I did some research
 and found [this](https://objectpartners.com/2014/12/11/copying-multiple-directories-in-a-single-gradle-task-with-up-to-date-checking/)

and created the following code (with Up-to-date check) based on it:

```
task resourcesCopy() {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from "src/main/resources"
            into "./target/dist/WEB-INF/classes"
        }
        copy {
            from "GeoIP2.conf"
            into "./target/dist/WEB-INF"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how long this syntax has been around, but it seems a little clearer.

```
task copyToRelease(dependsOn: [deletePreviousRelease], type: Copy) {
    from('build/dist') {
        include '**/*.*'
    }
    destinationDir(new File('../htmlrelease/src/main/webapp/canvas')) 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe also helpful: Usage of `fileTree` to copy an entire directory recursively, e.g.,

```
task mytest << {
    copy {
        from fileTree('.')
        into "mytest"
    }
}
```