# Gradle move directory to root before war is generated

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a `.war` which must have an entry point that can be run by command line, so the directory of the class must be on the root of the `.war` file.

How can I move the directory to the root of the war?

I tried:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}

war {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': '____embedded.____EntryPoint'
        )
    }
}

tasks.register('moveEntryPoint') {
    description 'Copies entrypoint to root dir.'
    doLast {
        ant.move file: "${buildDir}/classes/java/main/____embedded/",
                 todir: "${buildDir}/____embedded/"
    }
}

compileJava.finalizedBy(moveEntryPoint)
```

When I try to build I get this error:

```
Received unknown event for /home/username/eclipse-workspace/apex/app/build/classes/java/main/____embedded
Stopping file watching and invalidating VFS after an error happened
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways to do this:

1. Don’t move, just copy.
   https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html

Then, attach your task it to `processResources`.

2. Tell war plugin to include a directory.

```
war {
    webAppDirectory = file('src/main/webapp')
    from 'src/rootContent' // adds a file-set to the root of the archive
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_customizing

Comment: I did `from 'src/main/java/____embedded/'` and it moved the `.java` file to the root, not the directory with the `.class`

Comment: @user5507535 Java files are source code, you need to copy the compiled classes. Sounds like creating the war is the least of your challenges.

Comment: Using `from 'build/classes/java/main/'` works, but what if I had other things in `main` directory? If I use `from 'build/classes/java/main/____embedded'` it just copies the files inside `____embedded`, not the whole directory.

Comment: @user5507535 If you wanna copy entire directory, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110073/839733).